# TimerTask Application Design issue

Tags: java, software-design, timertask

I am working on java TimerTask Scheduler Application. I have main class as Service which is running as Scheduler.

I have `TaskSchedule() extends TimerTask` class which is used for fixed time execution as:

```
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TaskSchedule(), ...)
```

Inside constructor for `TaskSchedule` I have a `dataHelper` class which interacts with database for fetching and updating values from database.
In the `TaskSchedule` class I am overriding `run` method of TimerTask.
And inside the run method I am calling database helper call with parameters as:

```
@Override
public void run(){
    dataHelper.fetchDataFromDB( ? )
}
```

Here the question I have placed, where I am stuck in design. I want to keep this parameter to database dynamic.

**One Solution** I though of is:
Passing database parameter throughout from service to TaskScheduler to dataHelper. But I am looking for better solution on the same at design level.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a shared variable, which you can set outside and also take is before "fetchDataFromDB". You have to care of synchronization. Use a mutex to secure the shared memory.
A another solution is, that you can use somethink like a listener and every time you want to fetch from the db the listener will now it and get the data from you.